# Google Sheets Filter Function if no value multiple columns

Tags: filter, google-sheets

I want to pull all relevant data from `Data!F:G` on this sheet: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18hJW4ojAbe1dUF1lDdSOI11cTEaMeJ6N-VZ6BB7LrAY/edit#gid=1162973857

I am assuming it's a filter function but want to ensure that all data is pulled if the fields in `Dashboard!C1:C5` are empty.

`=filter(Data!F:G,
         Data!A:A = C1, 
         Data!B:B = C2, 
         Data!C:C = C3,
         Data!D:D = C4, 
         Data!E:E = C5)`

works when all fields are complete but not if one of them is empty.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no wild card in Google Sheets Filter unfortunately, but you could test if a column is equal to itself like this

```
=filter(Data!F:G,Data!A:A = if(C1="",Data!A:A,C1), Data!B:B = if(C2="",Data!B:B,C2), Data!C:C = if(C3="",Data!C:C,C3), Data!D:D = if(C4="",Data!D:D,C4), Data!E:E = if(C5="",Data!E:E,C5))
```

[image]

This is probably a bit tidier (the equivalent of an OR expression in a filter)

```
=filter(Data!F:G,(C1="")+(Data!A:A=C1), (C2="")+(Data!B:B=C2), (C3="")+(Data!C:C=C3), (C4="")+(Data!D:D = C4), (C5="")+(Data!E:E=C5))
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
=iferror(query(Data!A:G, "select F, G where F is not null" &IF(len(C1), " and A = '"&C1&"'",)&IF(len(C2), " and B = '"&C2&"'",)&IF(len(C3), " and C = '"&C3&"'",)&IF(len(C4), " and D = '"&C4&"'",)&IF(len(C5), " and E = '"&C5&"'",),0), "no matches found")
```